# How to convert $3\sin(x)\cos(x)$ into expression involving only $\sin (x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to convert $3\sin(x)\cos(x)$ to an expression involving only $\sin (x)$, but I don't know how.

Can you please point me to solutions.

Thanks!!!

EDIT:

I can do something like this: $$3\sin(x)\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$$ but how can I convert this so that I have only $\sin(x)$ ?

Comment: $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: $\cos x=\sqrt {1-\sin^2 x}$ (care with signs required)

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks for the answer, but can you explain to me what have you written

Comment: OK, I got is $sin(2x)=sin(x+x)=...$. It is adding two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the double angle formula for $\sin(2x)$: $$2\sin x \cos x = \sin(2x)\;\text{ and }\;\sin x \cos x = \frac 12 \sin(2x)$$

---

$$3\sin x \cos x = 2\sin x \cos x + \sin x \cos x = \sin(2x) + \frac 12 \sin (2x) = \dfrac 32 \sin (2x)$$

Comment: I did it a little diffrently $3*\sin(x)*\cos(x)=3*(\frac{2}{2})*\sin(x)*\cos(x)=(\frac{3}{2})*\sin(2x)$

Comment: That's just fine! ;-)

Comment: Sorry to say that all the answers did not satisfy the requirement - "convert 3sin(x)cos(x) to an expression involving only sin(x)". [:-)] Maybe the owner of the problem needed to edit his/her statement to reflect the actual required.

Comment: Good basic points. Enough for killing the problem. Hi :-)